# The quartic polynomial P(x) satisfies P(1)=0 and attains its maximum value of 3 at both x=2 and x=3. What is the absolute value of P(5)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

So far I have tried to set another quartic polynomial as P(x) - 3.

I will call this quartic polynomial as f(x), so I got that F(x) = P(x) - 3, and I knew that the roots of this polynomial is at x=2 and x=3. I got then that F(x) = a(x-2)(x-3), and so P(x) = a(x-2)(x-3) +3. I got a=-3/4, and so I got that P(5) = -9/2.

However, the correct answer was -24. Can anyone explain what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good idea. Your p(x) is not a quartic but since 3 is a maximum this means 2 and 3 are multiple roots of f(x)

Comment: @Cretin2 ok thanks! I changed my F(x) to a(x-2)^2(x-3)^2 and did the same for P(x) and I solved it

Comment: Also how did you get -3/4 for a ? You should get $p(x)=a(x-2)^2(x-3)^2+3$ a=-3/4 from p(1)=0. $p(5)=9\cdot 4\cdot(-3/4)+3=-27+3=-24$

Comment: Use math environement with $ around your formulas.

Comment: Note that you could integrate $a(x-2)(x-3)$ and multiply the result by $x-1$ too

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) as Cretin2 has already said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your P(x) is not a quartic polynomial,second your P(x) has no maxima at x=2 or x=3 it only has the values 3 at these x